# I trying to add quotation mark at the start of first line and then at the end of every 50th line

Tags: notepad++

I trying to add quotation mark at the start of first line and then at the end of every 50th line I have like 500 plus lines in notepad++ can anyone help

This is what my file look like

```
your text
your text
your text
```

and I want it to look like

```
"your text
your text
your text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for quotes every 3 lines, just modify the number to add quotes every 50 lines.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:.+\R){2}.+`
- Replace with: `"$0"`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
){2}        # end group must appear twice, in your case, you have to use 49 instead of 2
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
```

**Replacement:**

```
"$0"        # whole match sround with quotes
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it helped a lot its saved my hours of work daily

Comment: Thank you very much it helped a lot its saved my hours of work daily

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++, open the find/ replace dialog with `Ctrl + H`.

Select "Regular expressions" as the Search Mode (leave the . matches newline box unchecked"

- Find What:    `(^[^\n]*(?:\n[^\n]*){0,50}$)`
- Replace with: `"\1"`

##### Explanation:

- `(...{})` Capturing group. e.g. `(abc){3}` matches abcabcabc. First group matches abc.

###### 1st Capturing Group

`^[^\n]*`

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `[^\n]` Match a single character that is not a line-feed (`\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10))
- `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)

###### Non-capturing group

`(?:\n[^\n]*){0,50}$`

- `(?:...)` A non-capturing group allows you to apply quantifiers to part of your regex but does not capture/assign an ID. For example, repeating 1-3 digits and a period 3 times can be done like this: `/(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/`
- `[^\n]` Match a single character that is not a line-feed (`\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10))
- `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line
- `{0,50}` matches the previous token between 0 and 50 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Tested in Notepadd++ v8.4.6.

Reference https://regex101.com/